# How to snap scroll effect in flutter?

Tags: flutter, scroll, widget

With the normal scroll effect, you are free to scroll how much ever you want, 
but I want to have a scrollable list but only scroll full widget or 1/4 of the widget.

something like this:-
[image]

How to get a scrolling effect?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html).

[image]

Here is the sample code. It has the paging animation. It also has attached listener to the `PageController`, which is useful to get current state.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var _controller = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.6);
  var _color = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.addListener(() {
      if (_controller.page < 0.5) {
        setState(() {
          _color = "yellow";
        });
      }
      if (_controller.page >= 0.5 && _controller.page < 1.5) {
        setState(() {
          _color = "red";
        });
      }
      if (_controller.page >= 1.5 && _controller.page < 2) {
        setState(() {
          _color = "blue";
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 200,
        ),
        Text(
          _color,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 100,
          child: PageView(
            controller: _controller, 
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: SizedBox(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.amber,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 200,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 200,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.lightBlue,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```